# Problem with my connection string (WPF application)

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, connection-string

I have a project with SQL bank. I was change SQL to SQL Server Express and detach `MobinaDb` (my database name) and copied the file to the `bin` folder.

After that, I open `MyWPFApplication` config and edit the conncetion string.

- My provider: EF
- Db Name = MobinaDb
- SQL = SQLExpress

My project opens, but after a few seconds, it closes again. No error is visible, only a white form...

Please help me...

Thank you...

```
<add name="MobinaDbEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/MobinaModel.csdl|res://*/MobinaModel.ssdl|res://*/MobinaModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\sqlexpress;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\MobinaDb.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: I suggest your app crashed, try to execute it with Debugger so you can see the exception that it's thrown

Comment: its open with my local SQL but after Export and Change Connection String....this problem !

Comment: It's not simple to use a detached MDF file from SQL Server in SQL Express, if that is what you are trying. The latest SQL Express is version 2019, so your SQL Server can't be any newer than this.